# Suspected Kernel Panic in Lubuntu 13.04

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, chromium

Recently, I re-installed Lubuntu 13.04 because of some error in the last OS installation.

Today, if I try to go to Chromium, it works for a while, and then says, "Aw, snap" because it runs out of RAM space. A few seconds later, the entire screen goes black.

It goes black, and in seconds, the screen is filled with the terminal code-lines. Some words what I could actually understand there, was "Kernel Panic".

I did some research, and I realized that this thingy saves our hardware from physical damage.

To answer this question, I would like you to answer these:

1. What is this Kernel Panic?
2. Is it really related to hardware problems?
3. What can I do to stop this? Because it is seriously annoying me.

And just so you know, this is the third re-installation of Lubuntu.

If you could solve this soon, I'd be VERY glad.

If there is something I need to specify, please comment.

Thanks in advance.

***EDIT:***

This Question is Closed.
Apparently, I have found the answer. Check below.

Comment: _What is this Kernel Panic?_ and _Is it really related to hardware problems?_ can be answered here. About _What can I do to stop this?_ you should either [report a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) or ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to answer the bit about *How to fix the kernel panic*

Okay, I know I'm the one who asked the question, but I later found out the answer myself.

However, I should thank 'Oli' , who had previously answered my question.

The answer is simple. Check your RAM.

Find out whether your RAM was connected loosely. Fix it tightly.

I opened up my motherboard and noticed that the RAM was loose. If you fix it properly, then the panic wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You're using up all your RAM (and I assume swap, if you have any) and then the computer is crashing? I think the solution is pretty simple. You've got  few choices that all revolve around the same core concepts:

- Use less RAM. Find more efficient applications, use fewer tabs, etc.
- Get more RAM. It's cheap and simple to install.
- Allocate more (or some if you don't have *any*) swap to allow the kernel to page RAM to disk (very slow!)

A Kernel panic is a crash that the Kernel can't continue execution from. It does everything it can to shut down devices and flush disks but apart from that, it's stuck and needs rebooting. Consider it a blue screen of death, just not blue.

They're usually hardware related because the Kernel is pretty good at protecting itself from software exceptions (for security as much as anything else). Hardware faults are unforseeable.

Comment: The thing is, it does no boot AT ALL now. And Chromium crashes even when using one tab: facebook. Will re-installing the OS help?